# Confused about integral notation

Tags: integration

[image]

What does a single integral with respect to dy*dx with A as its lower bound mean? I keep seeing this and I get so confused, because I've only ever seen an integral like this but with 2 integral signs at the start. Do they both mean the same thing or do they have different meanings?

Comment: Presumably, $A$ is a region in the plane, and you're integrating over that region.

Comment: A single integral sign can denote a “multi variable” integrable if you so wish

Comment: An integral always takes place over a domain on which the integrand function is defined. For instance, in one variable an alternate notation for $\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$ is $\int_{[0, 1]} f(x)\,dx$. In the pictured example, this is a function of two variables being integrated over a two-dimensional region in the plane that is being called $A$.